# Algolia vue-instantsearch - Deleting a result

Tags: vuejs2, algolia, vue-instant-search

I'm currently experimenting with Algolia. It's really impressive so far. However, I've hit a bit of a 'roadblock'.

I'm using the `vue-instantsearch` package. It's currently in use only on a administration page. On this page I can click a button to bring up a modal, which confirms whether or not it should be deleted. I'm struggling to find a method to 'simply' *remove* the specified article from the results, without reloading.

I've essentially scoured the documentation and I've found the `deleteObjects` method, but it's not accessible from within the `ais-index` component, nor any of it's child components.

So, my question really is, is how would I go about correctly implementing this?

Any help with this matter would be *greatly* appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I appear to have solved my own issue.

Here is how I fixed it.

First off, I created my own instance of a `searchStore`

```
const searchStore = createFromAlgoliaCredentials(
    'APP_ID',
    'SEARCH_KEY'
);
```

Once I instantiated the search store, I passed it to the `ais-index` Vue component, via the `:search-store` prop.

That works like a normal `vue-instantsearch` component.

To remove the 'thing' from the results, I had to loop through the search store and remove the result. There are two results objects within the search store. The one I needed was the one prefixed with an underscore, which is accessible via `this.store._results` (`this` refers to the Vue component, which has access to the search store).

The full code to remove a result:

```
this.store._results = this.store._results.filter(loopedArticle => {
    return loopedArticle.objectID !== article.objectID;
});
```

It may be *improper* to use the search store this way, and access a 'private' property in this fashion, but it is the only way I could get it to work.

Hope this helps anyone else out who requires this functionality!